# How to remove spaces while writing in INI file- Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, configparser

I am using a  file and i have one section named DIR in which it contain the paths.
EX:

```
[DIR]
DirTo=D:\Ashish\Jab Tak hai Jaan
DirBackup = D:\Parser\ERICSSON_CSCORE_STANDARD_VMS\Backup
ErrorDir = D:\Parser\ERICSSON_CSCORE_STANDARD_VMS\Error

CombinerDir = D:\Parser\ERICSSON_CSCORE_STANDARD_VMS\Combiner
DirFrom=D:\Parser\ERICSSON_CSCORE_STANDARD_VMS\In
PidFileDIR = D:\Parser\ERICSSON_CSCORE_STANDARD_VMS\Pid
LogDir = D:\Parser\ERICSSON_CSCORE_STANDARD_VMS\Log   
TempDir = D:\Parser\ERICSSON_CSCORE_STANDARD_VMS\Temp
```

Now I want to replace the paths which I have done it but when I replaced its giving me spaces after and before the delimiter in the newly written `.ini` file. For example: `DirTo =  D:\Parser\Backup`. How I remove these spaces?

Code:

```
def changeINIfile():
    config=ConfigParser.RawConfigParser(allow_no_value=False)
    config.optionxform=lambda option: option
    cfgfile=open(r"D:\Parser\ERICSSON_CSCORE_STANDARD_VMS\Windows\opx_PAR_GEN_660_ERICSSON_CSCORE_STANDARD_PM_VMS_MALAYSIA.ini","w")
    config.set('DIR','DirTo','D:\Ashish\Jab Tak hai Jaan')
    config.optionxform=str
    config.write(cfgfile)
    cfgfile.close()
```

Comment: Please post the code you are using to write these lines of text. Martijn Pieters correctly suggests that you can use `strip()` to remove whitespace from the start and end of a string, but a code sample would help us debug better.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to update it with code.

Comment: Use [raw strings](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals) or double escape your \, or use `os.path.join` for your paths. Also, as I see it the Python code is not creating any extra spaces, so what exactly is your question?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem; no whitespace is added when I use your `.set()` call. Or did you mean the spaces around the ` = ` equals? Those are part of the format; the standard `.ini` file format allows for those spaces.

Comment: Note that the Win32 INI parser will ignore this whitespace (it has some rather interesting behaviour, but that at least is one sensible one). So it may not actually be a problem for you beyond cosmetics.

Comment: @Martijn: there may be differences between setting and adding values; I can't remember clearly with configparser.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: I tried both.

Comment: You could also use sômething like `iniparse`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the definition of `RawConfigParser.write`:

```
def write(self, fp):
    """Write an .ini-format representation of the configuration state."""
    if self._defaults:
        fp.write("[%s]\n" % DEFAULTSECT)
        for (key, value) in self._defaults.items():
            fp.write("%s = %s\n" % (key, str(value).replace('\n', '\n\t')))
        fp.write("\n")
    for section in self._sections:
        fp.write("[%s]\n" % section)
        for (key, value) in self._sections[section].items():
            if key != "__name__":
                fp.write("%s = %s\n" %
                         (key, str(value).replace('\n', '\n\t')))
        fp.write("\n")
```

As you can see, the `%s = %s\n` format is hard-coded into the function.  I think your options are:

1. Use the INI file with whitespace around the equals
2. Overwrite `RawConfigParser`'s `write` method with your own
3. Write the file, read the file, remove the whitespace, and write it again

If you're 100% sure option 1 is unavailable, here's a way to do option 3:

```
def remove_whitespace_from_assignments():
    separator = "="
    config_path = "config.ini"
    lines = file(config_path).readlines()
    fp = open(config_path, "w")
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line.startswith("#") and separator in line:
            assignment = line.split(separator, 1)
            assignment = map(str.strip, assignment)
            fp.write("%s%s%s\n" % (assignment[0], separator, assignment[1]))
        else:
            fp.write(line + "\n")
```

Comment: Hi Slace..Yup the 3 solution worked for me..thankyou so much :)

Comment: In Python 3, you can use `config.write(file_on_disk, space_around_delimiters=False)`. See [Python 3 Documentation: configparser.write](http://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.write)

Answer (score 14):

I ran into this problem to and I came up with an additional solution.

- I didn't want to replace the function as future versions of Python might change the internal function structures of RawConfigParser.
- I also didn't want to read the file back in right after it was written because that seemed wasteful

Instead I wrote a wrapper around the file object which simply replaces " = " with "=" in all lines written though it.

```
class EqualsSpaceRemover:
    output_file = None
    def __init__( self, new_output_file ):
        self.output_file = new_output_file

    def write( self, what ):
        self.output_file.write( what.replace( " = ", "=", 1 ) )

config.write( EqualsSpaceRemover( cfgfile ) )
```

Comment: Most elegant and flexible solution. The write function can easily be extended to perform other kinds of filtering.

Comment: I would use write.replace(" = ", "=", 1) so you don't change any values that happen to have " = " in them

Comment: The simple replace() above may change comments or even section names. To see how `crudini --ini-options=nospace ...` implements this replacement see https://github.com/pixelb/crudini/commit/65ace170

Answer (score 3):

I know it's a very old question but the latest version of `Configparser` has simple solution. Just use:

> parser.write(file_pointer, space_around_delimiters=False)