# ConfigParser reads capital keys and make them lower case

Tags: python, python-2.7

I found one interesting observation.
I had written one config file read program as,

```
import ConfigParser
class  ConfReader(object):
    ConfMap = dict()

    def __init__(self):
        self.config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
        self.config.read('./Config.ini')
        self.__loadConfigMap()

    def __loadConfigMap(self):
        for sec in self.config.sections():
            for key,value in self.config.items(sec):
                print 'key = ', key, 'Value = ', value
                keyDict = str(sec) + '_' + str(key)
                print 'keyDict = ' + keyDict  
                self.ConfMap[keyDict] = value

    def getValue(self, key):
        value = ''
        try:
            print ' Key = ', key
            value = self.ConfMap[key] 
        except KeyError as KE:
            print 'Key', KE , ' didn\'t found in configuration.'
    return value

class MyConfReader(object):
    objConfReader = ConfReader()

def main():
     print MyConfReader().objConfReader.getValue('DB2.poolsize')
     print MyConfReader().objConfReader.getValue('DB_NAME')

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

And my Config.ini file looks like,

```
[DB]
HOST_NAME=localhost
NAME=temp
USER_NAME=postgres
PASSWORD=mandy
```

The  __loadConfigMap() works just fine. But while reading the key and values, it is making the keys lower case. I didn't understand the reason. Can any one please explain why it is so?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preserve case in ConfigParser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611799/preserve-case-in-configparser)

Answer (score 175, accepted):

`ConfigParser.ConfigParser()` is documented to behave this way, in the [*Mapping Protocol Access* section](https://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html#mapping-protocol-access):

> By default, all keys in sections are accessible in a case-insensitive manner. E.g. `for option in parser["section"]` yields only `optionxform`’ed option key names. This means lowercased keys by default.

That's because this module parses Windows INI files which are expected to be parsed case-insensitively.

You can disable this behaviour by replacing the [`ConfigParser.optionxform()` function](https://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.optionxform):

```
self.config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
self.config.optionxform = str
```

`str` passes through the options unchanged.

Comment: @Martijin this means I need to replace the code of ConfigParser.RawConfigParser(). Fine, thank you for the explanation. Works for me.

Comment: Thanks for explaining **why** `ConfigParser` is converting the keys to lowercase.

Comment: With this option, i see that CAPITALS are retained for the keys. In my ini file i don't have any spaces between the key and value. But, config parser is adding a space before and after the equal to. For example: if i have KEY=value in my ini file, it is changed to KEY = value. Is there any option to avoid these extra spaces?

Comment: I found the solution for the space issue in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14021135/how-to-remove-spaces-while-writing-in-ini-file-python

Comment: Mypy complains that we 'cannnot assign to a method' on this line: self.config.optionxform = str

Comment: @uuu777: well, Mypy is wrong there. This is one of those exceptions where it is okay to shadow the class implementation of a method. Just add `# type: ignore` on the line.