# Zeppelin: How to add python files in PYTHONPATH

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I am running zeppelin with Spark on yarn. 
Option --py-files(SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS) does not work in zeppelin. Is there any alternative to --py-files in zeppelin.

NOTE: I can upload files using option: --files but then it does not add those files in PYTHONPATH. Hence I need an alternative to --py-files in zeppelin.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Zeppelin, but you can achieve the equivalent of `--py-files` by using the `addPyFile` method on the context (See https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/python/pyspark.html). HTH

Comment: I was able to get over the problem by replicating the python files to all nodes in the cluster and then updating PYTHONPATH accordingly while starting zeppelin.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40808064/pyspark-append-executor-environment-variable